# I used ">NUL 2>&1" on a 7-Zip command line script

Tags: cmd.exe, 7-zip

The thing is, it seems to work, but I think it's ignoring the second half. Does it make sense to use this on an app like 7-Zip?

Comment: What makes you think it isn't working? The redirection should throw away all output.

Comment: It is working, but I'm wondering if the "2>&1" is necessary for 7-Zip, or is just ignored?

Comment: It is necessary if you want to discard any error output.

Comment: So 7-Zip operates the same as MS-DOS commands then? That's a relief.

Comment: cmd.exe is not ms-dos, but essentially all command line programs will support redirection in the same way.